# Browser returns to tab when save operation completes, but I do not want it to return to that tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser

I have an Mvc application which uses api requests for db operations.

My problem is I have a page that when user clicks update, sends an async requests to api which takes some time (like a minute)to complete, and gives an update completed message on update completed. But users says because update operation takes time, they hit update button, change tab and start working on something other, and when the update operation finishes and page alerts that operation complete, browser (chrome) switches to that tab automatically. Users says this is annoying and they do not want the page that updates to switches back automatically.

Is there any way to prevent this action.

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("RemarkDetailPost", "LawRemark")",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData + "&selectedUsers=" + selectedUsers,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#loading-div-background").hide();
                //alert("Update completed");
                window.location.reload(true);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                $("#loading-div-background").hide();
                alert(exception);
            }
        });
```

Here is my code, it is the `alert("Update completed");` line that steals the focus on tabs. I know I can display my message in various other ways, but I want to learn that is it possible to prevent alert to switch to that page back
Kind Regards.

Comment: We would need to see your code where you are making api request. So that we can find the issue and help accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It is said that this behavior is browser specific, I have seen some people open bug fix requests for this issue in development forums of chrome and firefox. The only solution I find is do not use js alerts, use modals instead.